# regular covering transformation

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

can you help me with proving this statement?

> >
>   Suppose that $F:S^1\longrightarrow S^1 $ such that  $F(z)=z^n$ , is a covering space.prove that $F$ is regular covering transformation

Honestly..i don't have any ideal to prove this statement.
Your help would be very useful for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F$ is a regular covering transformation if $F_{*}(\pi_1(S^1, s_0)) \lhd \pi_1(S^1, s_0).$ But $\pi_1(S^1, s_0) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, so every subgroup is normal, and hence every covering map is regular.

$F_{*}(\pi_1(S^1, S_0))$ is a subgroup of $\pi_1(S^1, s_0)$ since the induced map of $F$, $F_{*}$, is a homomorphism.

Comment: Thank you a lot this is the right answer i wanted...Can you help me for the solution of my one question before the end that i asked before this question? @klint